# How to add class dynamically to list tag<li>, in Imagepicker.js.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have added classes and id's to div and images dynamically, in this way it is working fine.
Original code is: starting from line number 274 in *image-picker.js*

```
ImagePickerOption.prototype.create_node = function() {
      var image, thumbnail;
      this.node = jQuery("<li/>");
      image = jQuery("<img class='image_picker_image'/>");
      image.attr("src", this.option.data("img-src"));
      thumbnail = jQuery("<div class='thumbnail'>");
      thumbnail.click({
        option: this
      }, function(event) {
        return event.data.option.clicked();
});
```

---

Code I have edited is:

```
ImagePickerOption.prototype.create_node = function() {
      var image, thumbnail;
      this.node = jQuery("<li/>");
      image = jQuery("<img class='image_picker_image'/>");
      image.attr("src", this.option.data("img-src"));
      thumbnail = jQuery("<div class='thumbnail mask' id='"+this.option.data("value")+"' onclick=changeImage('"+this.option.data("img-src")+"','"+this.option.data("value")+"');>   ");
      thumbnail.click({
        option: this
      }, function(event) {
        return event.data.option.clicked();
});
```

---

I wanted to add a class or `id` to `li` tag, line 123 in *image-picker.js*:

```
container.append(jQuery("<li class='group_title'>" + 
(option_group.attr("label")) + "</li>"));
```

But it is not getting added and even I can't see this default class added by them is not added nowhere in html.
So can you please suggest me how can I add some class here, so that it must be added in html too like this

```
container.append(jQuery("<li class='group_title some_class'>" +   
(option_group.attr("label")) + "</li>"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add while creating the element itself as below:

```
ImagePickerOption.prototype.create_node = function() {
      var image, thumbnail;
      this.node = jQuery("<li/>", {
           class: 'yourclassnamehere',//here add your class
           id:'someid' //note: this should be unique
      }); 
      image = jQuery("<img class='image_picker_image'/>");
      image.attr("src", this.option.data("img-src"));
      thumbnail = jQuery("<div class='thumbnail'>");
      thumbnail.click({
        option: this
      }, function(event) {
        return event.data.option.clicked();
      }
);
```

Comment: Anytime.. @NaveenKumarK Do accept it as answer if it has helped you and let others don't waste their time answering this again!

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I get all the selected pictures in it? @guruprasad-rao

Comment: @NaveenKumarK You might need to post it as separate question giving some brief detail on that. Then you will get many solutions. This is as per SO rule. .. :)

Comment: Ok thanks for suggesting ... I am new in using SO... so need to know more about SO rules :) @GuruprasadRao